# Using bash to check a large number of folders for images who do not have matching downloadable versions

Tags: bash

A co-worker was asking how they could possibly solve this problem in bash (or if there was a better tool, that would be fine too).

We have a large number of folders all containing images. They might be named 12345.jpg. Some of them, residing in the same folder, might have 12345_download.jpg. We want to try and find all the files that do not have a matching downloadable version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little help of [extglobs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)…

This will get you the files you want in folder `/path/to/folder/`:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob

for f in /path/to/folder/!(*_download).jpg; do
    if [[ ! -e ${f%.jpg}_download.jpg ]]; then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

Now run this for each folder.

Comment: Or even `for f in **/!(*_download).jpg` for a directory tree (requires `shopt -s globstar`).

Comment: So I think this is putting me on the right track and I understand what it is trying to do. At the moment however, when I run the command, it actually just outputs /folderpath/!(*-download).jpg

Comment: @BehemothDan are you running this in Bash or in sh?